# UML diagrams for massage chair

Tags: uml

I need to draw a few different UML diagrams for massage chair system.
There is a remote control which controls functions of the chair, chair with a few motors which are massaging and everything is connected with coin system, but coin system is optional. I don't know where to start, if to focus only on the chair and what is happening in there. Or that for example remote control sends command to the chair to do back massage.
Can u please give me some examples from your point of view?

Comment: You've got to show some effort in your original post, or you'll be downvoted. That's how it works. You simply explained a problem you've been having, without explaining how you've attempted to fix it or what your thought process has been up to this point. Don't take it personally, just improve the question to show that you've done your homework too! Of course, that's just my $.02

Comment: @knowbody If any question could be asked, StackOverflow wouldn't have downvotes/closing questions, but it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would really help if you mentioned which UML diagrams you're interested in (eg. Use Case, Class etc.). Each one has each own requirements.

First of all, I think you need to specify the entities in your project (eg. users, operators, system) and what their functional roles and actions are.

Ok, I guess a possible use case diagram for the user would be...

actor_customer:

- pays
- selects part of the body --extend--> head / back / etc
- selects speed/intensity

maybe start(wich includes the selections)/stop/pause

Comment: I need to do about 5 different UML diagrams. To start of course I need use case, then I will be fine

Answer (score 1):

Look at [DatabaseAnswers](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) for some examples of data models... You should be able to create a decent UML diagram by modifying those to your needs.

Comment: Thank you I will try to look for some hints, I've done already some projects with UML. I'm just stacked with this one. Don't know where to start